# python discord: get_member() doesnt return a member object

Tags: python, discord, attributeerror

I have a discord Bot which ran just fine, somehow I ran into a problem where I wanted to get the name of the Member in my Discord-Server. It just says that None has no attribute name which leads me to thinking the function might not be working properly... Im just showcasing the error im getting:

```
import discord

TOKEN = ""

class DiscordClass(discord.Client):

    async def on_message(self, message):
        user_id = message.author.id
        member = message.guild.get_member(user_id)
        print(member.name)

client = DiscordClass()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

OUT: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

PS: I'm new to Stackoverflow if i did something wrong explaining wise im sorry

Edit:
Really i dont really know what I have been doing here, the documentations weren't helpful (atleast for me, I have been using them for all the other things... I might be not at advanced in python as i should be for solving this issue)

```
import discord

TOKEN = ""

class discordClass(discord.AutoShardedClient):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(fetch_all_members=True)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        user_id = message.author.id
        member = message.guild.get_member(user_id)
        print(message.guild.owner)
        print(member.name)

client = discordClass()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

OUT: still the same Error

In the docs they said using 'chunk_guilds_at_startup' would be another option... did that and I got this: "ValueError: Intents.members must be enabled to chunk guilds at startup."

Answer (score 0):

from the [Discord API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) you can see "If fetch_offline_members is set to False then the user cache will not exist. This makes it difficult or impossible to do many things, for example:

- Guild.get_member() will usually be unavailable."

So your member variable has no type, and therefore also no attribute called name.

Maybe set fetch_offline_members to True and try again!

Cheers, miGa

Edit: As you said, chunk_guilds_at_startup is the new attribute for fetch_offline_members. And when you set this to True you get another error message. So Intents.members must be set to True!

Comment: Maybe try to set Intents.members to True then?